# Prevent links hover effect from logo

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar with logo. I wanted the logo to be clickable so I can assign it to home page when clicked. I used `<a href=“#”<img src=“../images/logo.jpg”><a>`.  Everything is working okay except one problem. I applied hover effects a.active, a:hover on the  ul links. Somehow I get the effect applied to the logo as well when I hover it on. I wanted it to apply to only the link that’s (Home, About, Services etc) and not the logo.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navcase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: coral
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  color: white;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="navcase">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="../logo/logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The problem is the logo also receives border effect when I hover on it. This shouldn’t be. I don’t want any effect on the logo

Comment: Just replace `a.active, a:hover` with `nav a.active, nav a:hover`

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
ul a.active,
ul a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
ul > li > a.active,
ul > li > a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Another nice solution.